# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Caused by mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have problem like in tittle imho in my code everything is all right i look for help on stack and none of these 3 topics help me so I create new one could someone look on my code ?

[Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454945/caused-by-org-hibernate-annotationexception-mappedby-reference-an-unknown-targ)

[I'm getting a mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property and I'm just not seeing the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198444/im-getting-a-mappedby-reference-an-unknown-target-entity-property-and-im-just)

[Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538118/caused-by-org-hibernate-annotationexception-mappedby-reference-an-unknown-targ)

```java
@Data
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
public class Currency
{
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
    String code;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "currency", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<CurrencyValue> currencyValue;

    public Currency(String name, String code)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Currency{" +
               "id=" + id +
               ", name='" + name + '\'' +
               ", code='" + code + '\'' +
               '}';
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
public class CurrencyValue
{
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    Long id;
    String code;
    String name;
    double value;
    Date date;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "currency")
    Currency Currency;

    public CurrencyValue(Double value, String code, String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.code = code;
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "CurrencyValue{" +
               "id=" + id +
               ", code='" + code + '\'' +
               ", value=" + value +
               ", date=" + date +
               '}';
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface CurrencyValueDAO extends CrudRepository<CurrencyValue, Long>
{

//I tried this 4 options. on each of them i had exception that i add below

    // List<CurrencyValue> findAllByCurrencyId(Long id);
   //  List<CurrencyValue> findAllByCurrency(Currency currency);
   // List<CurrencyValue> findCurrencyValuesByCurrency_Id(Long id);
    //List<CurrencyValue> findAllByCurrency_Code(Currency currency);
}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.bartosz.kolej.stock.currency.domain.CurrencyValue.currency in com.bartosz.kolej.stock.currency.domain.Currency.currencyValue
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.bartosz.kolej.stock.VirtualStockMarketApplication.main(VirtualStockMarketApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.bartosz.kolej.stock.currency.domain.CurrencyValue.currency in com.bartosz.kolej.stock.currency.domain.Currency.currencyValue
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:842) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:793) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:903) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:934) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `Currency Currency;` >> `Currency currency;`

Comment: In `CurrencyValue` you have a typo as @AlanHay mentioned.

Comment: I was looking for that 4h :D Thank u !

Comment: @AlanHay please post answers as answers not as comments. I'm tired of looking at already answered questions. Thank you!